# SOLR getting started, little help

Tags: java, mysql, windows, linux, solr

I have managed to install SOLR and run the admin interface...

I have no clue on how to add indexes to SOLR...

I have a virtual server (wampserver) and in the SOLR tutorial they are referring to a TERMINAL all the time... I guess they mean the LINUX terminal or something, but how should I do the same thing in windows OS?

For instance, I can add xml files to the post.jar file to POST indexes to SOLR, but how do I do this?

ALSO, how do I go about if I want to add indexes to SOLR from MYSQL ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the [tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html) carefully, it shows exactly how to run post.jar to add documents:

```
user:~/solr/example/exampledocs$ java -jar post.jar solr.xml monitor.xml
```

The equivalent of the Linux terminal on Windows is the [command prompt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_Prompt).

To import data from a RDBMS take a look at the [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler).